# How to do update in laravel using foreach loop with querybuilder

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I got a table named `schools` and i got a column there `lat`and `long` i defined it as empty because i want it to fill later with the coordinates using google geocode. Now that I already setup my api for google geocode and got the coords. I want to update the column `lat`and `long` in my database using the geocode api and querybuilder. I used foreach query but when i do `dd` it prints the last data. Can someone tell me what I should to to update them all? thanks.

DB structure

```
+---------------------------------------------+---------------------------+-------------+-----+-----+
| school_name                                 | address                   | postal_code | lat | lng |
+---------------------------------------------+---------------------------+-------------+-----+-----+
| NGEE ANN SECONDARY SCHOOL                   | 1 TAMPINES STREET 32      | 529283      |     |     |
| SINGAPORE SPORTS SCHOOL                     | 1 CHAMPIONS WAY           | 737913      |     |     |
| NUS HIGH SCHOOL OF MATHEMATICS AND SCIENCE  | 20 CLEMENTI AVENUE 1      | 129957      |     |     |
| SCHOOL OF THE ARTS, SINGAPORE               | 1 ZUBIR SAID DRIVE        | 227968      |     |     |
| NORTHLIGHT SCHOOL                           | 151 TOWNER ROAD           | 327830      |     |     |
| ASSUMPTION PATHWAY SCHOOL                   | 30 CASHEW ROAD            | 679697      |     |     |
| SCHOOL OF SCIENCE AND TECHNOLOGY, SINGAPORE | 1 TECHNOLOGY DRIVE        | 138572      |     |     |
| CREST SECONDARY SCHOOL                      | 561 JURONG EAST STREET 24 | 609561      |     |     |
| SPECTRA SECONDARY SCHOOL                    | 1 WOODLANDS DRIVE 64      | 737758      |     |     |
+---------------------------------------------+---------------------------+-------------+-----+-----+
```

Here is my code

```
  public function geocode(){
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $geocoder = new Geocoder($client);
        $geocoder->setApiKey(config('geocoder.key'));
        $postals = \DB::table('schools')
                        ->select('postal_code')
                        ->get();        
        foreach ($postals as $postal){
            $address = $geocoder->getCoordinatesForAddress($postal->postal_code);
        }
        dd($address);
    }
```

What i got in response is

```
  "lat" => 1.4364557
  "lng" => 103.8043789
  "accuracy" => "ROOFTOP"
  "formatted_address" => "1 Woodlands Drive 64, Singapore 737758"
  "viewport" => {#609 ▶}
  "address_components" => array:6 [▶]
  "place_id" => "ChIJTXT5XbwR2jERbkmADGYcJ4U"
]
```

The response is from the last data which has a postal of `737758`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dd()` return the last data, because you set value to address in every loop, at last address return the last value.

If you want to update it, you can do it like this:

```php
        foreach ($postals as $postal){
            $address = $geocoder->getCoordinatesForAddress($postal->postal_code);
            DB::table('schools')
                    ->where('postal', $postal->postal_code)
                    ->update(['lat' => $address['lat'], 'lng' => $address['lng']]);
        }
```

Comment: its you again sir @TsaiKoga. Thanks for the answer and explanation. This is the most accurate answer for me. Should try this first

Comment: @Vince glad it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the `$address` variable as array and try

```
foreach ($postals as $postal){
    $address[] = $geocoder->getCoordinatesForAddress($postal->postal_code);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you know the postal code which address you have queried for, and you have according lat/lng values.

Now you must extract the values from the answer and build the UPDATE query text. For the shown answer it is

```
UPDATE schoools
SET  lat = 1.4364557        /* $address->lat */
   , lng = 103.8043789      /* $address->lng */
WHERE postal_code = 737758; /* $postal->postal_code */
```

Then you must execute it. Do this in the same `foreach ($postals as $postal)` cycle for each postal code.

You may also update the `address` field (or insert the field `formatted_address` and update it).

Comment: it seems confusing to me sir. but thanks for the answer.. i will try this.

Comment: @Vince **TsaiKoga** [shows absolutely the same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59728275/10138734) in Laravel syntax.

Comment: yes. @Akina thanks for answering my question, I upvoted your answer for respect.